# How do I parse JSON in Pig?

Tags: json, apache-pig

I have a lot of gzip'd log files in s3 that has 3 types of log lines: b,c,i.  i and c are both single level json:

```
{"this":"that","test":"4"}
```

Type b is deeply nested json.  I came across this [gist](https://gist.github.com/601331) talking about compiling a jar to make this work.  Since my java skills are less than stellar, I didn't really know what to do from here.

```
{"this":{"foo":"bar","baz":{"test":"me"},"total":"5"}}
```

Since types i and c are not always in the same order, this makes specifying everything in the generate regex difficult.  Is handling JSON (in a gzip'd file) possible with Pig?  I am using whichever version of Pig comes built on an Amazon Elastic Map Reduce instance.

This boils down to two questions:
1) Can I parse JSON with Pig (and if so, how)?
2) If I can parse JSON (from a gzip'd logfile), can I parse nested JSON objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a lot of workarounds and working through things, I was able to answer to get this done.  I did a write-up about it on my blog about how to do this.  It is available here: http://eric.lubow.org/2011/hadoop/pig-queries-parsing-json-on-amazons-elastic-map-reduce-using-s3-data/

Comment: "Error establishing a database connection" on the link

Answer (score 17):

Pig 0.10 comes with builtin JsonStorage and  JsonLoader().

[pig doc for json load/store](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#jsonloadstore)

Comment: This question brings up a good concern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396550/loading-json-with-varying-schema-into-pig

Answer (score 5):

Pig comes with a JSON loader. 
To load you use:

> A = LOAD ‘data.json’
>       USING PigJsonLoader();

To store you can use:

```
STORE INTO ‘output.json’ 
    USING PigJsonLoader();
```

However, I'm not sure it supports GZIPed data....

Comment: where/what version?  0.8.0 doesn't seem to know about it by default.

Comment: PigJsonLoader seems to be a separate package? https://github.com/mmay/PigJsonLoader

Answer (score 3):

Please try this: https://github.com/a-b/elephant-bird

Answer (score 2):

We can do it by using JsonLoader...But we have to mention the schema for your json data or else it may arise an error..just follow the below link

```
         http://joshualande.com/read-write-json-apache-pig/
```

We can also do it by creating  UDF to parse it...

Answer (score 0):

You can try usin the twitter elephantbird json loader , It handles the json data dynamically.But you have to be very precise with the schema .

api_data = LOAD 'file name' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad');

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the usage of twitter elephantbird increase a lot and it is quickly becoming the goto library for json parsing in PIG.

Example :

```
DEFINE TwitterJsonLoader com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad=true ');

JsonInput = LOAD 'input_path' USING TwitterJsonLoader() AS (entity: map[]);

InputObjects = FOREACH JsonInput GENERATE (map[]) entity#'Object' AS   JsonObject;

InputIds = FOREACH InputObjects GENERATE JsonObject#'id' AS id;
```