# Parse a JSON-formatted string in Pig

Tags: regex, json, apache-pig

I'm using pig to analyze data loaded from Cassandra. One of the columns that I get is a string with product ids and product information in JSON format:

> ```
> row | ... |                              items                                       | ...  
>  1  | ... | "[{"id":"1", "useless_info":"blah"}, {"id":"2", "useless_info":"bleh"}]" | ...          
>  2  | ... | "[{"id":"3"}]"                                                           | ...  
>  .  |  .  |                                   .                                      |  .
> ```

Note that some of the rows will have additional stuff within the string, while others will only have id.

Anyways, what I need to do is to parse each "items" string and generate id numbers:

> ```
> row | id | ... |  
>  1  | 1  | ... |  
>  1  | 2  | ... |  
>  2  | 3  | ... |  
> etc
> ```

From what I understand, there are no JSON parsers for Pig out there, only load and store functions (like elephantbird). Is it possible to do what I want with something like REGEX_EXTRACT or will I have to write my own UDF (or is there a better, prettier, and more clever way)?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

PS I'm using Pig 0.93

Comment: Possible dup of [How do I parse JSON in Pig?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5013003/90527)

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that blog post - they are using [elephantbird](http://eric.lubow.org/2011/hadoop/pig-queries-parsing-json-on-amazons-elastic-map-reduce-using-s3-data/)  to _load_ the JSON-formatted data. My data is actually all strings (and already loaded into Pig), and only one part has JSON-like format (that needs to be parsed)

Answer (score 1):

Elephant Bird has [JsonStringToMap](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/piggybank/JsonStringToMap.java), which parses a JSON String and outputs a Map in Pig. This is distinct from their [JsonLoader](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/load/JsonLoader.java), which parses JSON while loading a file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Although we needed to something different, it was relatively straightforward to write a UDF based on JsonStringToMap, despite just basic knowledge of java.