# Load JSON format table into Pig

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a table created with Hive. It takes a `JSON` format data (I have used `SERDE` to create it).

I would like to know if it is possible to load data from this table to `Pig` and then make some transformations.

This is my JSON data:

```
{"id":"1", "word":"2" ,"flag":1}.
```

Do you have any clue?

---

I have tried

```
A = LOAD ‘data.json’
USING PigJsonLoader();
```

but with no success. This is the error I get:

> [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:   Unexpected character ''

I turned to

```
json_objects = LOAD 'hdfs://user/cloudera/test.json' 
               USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.JsonLoader();
```

but it says:

> Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.JsonLoader using
>   imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.].

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Pig?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013003/how-do-i-parse-json-in-pig)

Answer (score 0):

Reason for your error is that class does not exist. If you are running pig in version 0.12.1 you'll find documentation about contributed piggybank at http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/package-summary.html